# Rhomobile APP VersionCode problem

Tags: android, rhomobile

I am trying to upload a test application to AndroidMarket. The deal is that I want to upload APKs for all versions, 1.6,2.0 and so on. But always I get error

The new apk's versionCode (10000) already exists.

It seams that always when building RhoHub sets VersionCode 10000.
How to fix this problem, and upload to Android Market all versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `build.yml` file of the application's root, try changing the `version` property.

Comment: version of the build?  do you mean  this part???
version: 1.0.0
vendor: rhomobile
build: debug
bbver: 4.6

Comment: There is a property called `version`.  Try changing that version with each build.  Sample build.yml here, where there is a line that says `version: 1.0.7`: https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes-system-api-samples/blob/master/build.yml